# Extracting URLS from json file

Tags: python, json, url, postman, extract

I used postman to get urls from an api so I can look at certain titles.
The response was saved as a .json file.

A snippet of my response.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "apiUrl":"https://api.ft.com/example/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735",
    "title": {
        "title": "Example title example title example title"
    },
    "lifecycle": {
        "initialPublishDateTime":"2020-01-21T22:54:57Z",
        "lastPublishDateTime":"2020-01-21T23:38:19Z"
    },
    "location":{
        "uri":"https://www.ft.com/exampleurl/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735"
    },
    "summary": "...",
    # ............(this continues for all different titles I found)
}
```

Since I want to look at the articles I want to generate a list of all urls. I am not interested in the apiUrl but only in the uri.

My current python file looks like this

```
with open ("My path to file/response.json") as file:
    for line in file:
        urls = re.findall('https://(?:[-\www.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', line)
        print(urls)
```

This gives me the following output:
`['https://api.ft.com', 'https://www.ft.com', 'https://api.ft.com', 'https://www.ft.com',........`

However, I want to be able to see the entire url for www.ft.com ( so not the api.ft.com url's since I'm not interested in those).
For example I want my program to extract something like: https://www.ft.com/thisisanexampleurl/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735

I want the program to do this for the entire response file

Does anyone know a way to do this?

All help would be appreciated.
Raymond

Comment: Could you provide a better snippet of your data? You'd probably be much better off using [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) instead of regexp, if the JSON is properly formatted.

Comment: Is this a one-level depth JSON? Does required URL always stored under `uri` key?

Comment: The wanted url alway follows after the uri key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input everyone.

I found another way to solve my issue ( I used the newsapi for python. essentially did the same, but instead to only look at the financial time api I now get way more sites and articles). This worked way better for me

Raymond van Zonneveld

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to extract from below is the simplest representation of it

```
str_='first url "https://api.ft.com/example/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735" plus second url "https://www.ft.com/exampleurl/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735'
import re
re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", str_)
Output=
['https://api.ft.com/example/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735"', 'https://www.ft.com/exampleurl/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735']
```

Comment: Dear.

Thanks for your awnser, however I think it does not help.
If I use
'''''with open ("/My Path to file/response.json") as file:
    for string in file:
        urls = ("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", string)
        print(urls)'''''''

The output generated is my entire file and unfortunately not only the wanted urls

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld once check these

Comment: looking at the output I don't think this is what I need. I only want the second url (https://www.ft.com/..........) and not the api url (https://api.ft.com/......)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the urls are scattered throughout the json object, you could recursively search each nested objects value at each key to determine whether or not its a url.

Also, if this is properly formatted json, using `json.loads` will be much easier to search through than a file object.

For example, using the python [validators](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package

```
import validators

Iterate through the object.

Check each value with -> `validators.url(value)`

If True -> return value
```

Comment: Dear @blakeyoder,

Thanks for the response, This might just be what I need. Could you perhaps elaborate on the steps? I seem to get stuck.
I imported validators and Checked by doing 'validators.url('www.ft.com').
However when I do 'If True -> return www.ft.com' I get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? Can you paste your full snippet?

Comment: I tried the following:
''''''import validators

with open('/Users/raymondvanzonneveld/Desktop/API Folder/response.json', 'r' ) as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
for line in data:
    validators.url('www.ft.com')
    if True:
        print('www.ft.com')''''''

I got rid of the syntax error, but now I just get loads of www.ft.com as a return, so not the full url

Comment: You're passing an incorrect value to `validators.url` You want to pass the value of the json key not a string literal. I'd recommend not reading it in as a file but loading it in as parsed json using `json.loads`. For that, there are plenty of tutorials around the web that will help turn a json string into a parsed object https://pythonbasics.org/read-json-file/ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure which keys contain URL you could use [`nested_lookup`](https://pypi.org/project/nested-lookup/) library to retrieve them:

```
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup

urls = []
for key in ('uri', 'apiUrl'):
    urls.extend(nested_lookup(key, data))
print(urls)

# ['https://www.ft.com/exampleurl/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735', 'https://api.ft.com/example/83example74-3c9b-11ea-a01a-example547046735']
```